# Call type's tagged constructor if available, default otherwise

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, void, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to build up some code that wants to declare a local variable (say of type `test`, as shown below). Construction of that local variable should use a constructor that takes a special `Tag` argument if such a constructor exists, or the default constructor otherwise.

What we've been able to come up with is as follows, where we specialize to construct either a `void` argument or a `Tag` argument, but compilers don't like that:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

struct Tag { };

template <bool z>
struct helper {
  using type = void;
};
template <>
struct helper<true> {
  using type = Tag;
};

template <bool z>
static typename helper<z>::type get_arg() {
  return typename helper<z>::type();
}

struct test {
  test(void) { cout << "test(void)\n"; }
  test(Tag x) { cout << "test(Tag)\n"; }

  test(const test&) = delete;
  test(test&&) = delete;
};

template <typename T>
void try_construct() {
  // we would be selecting from one of these by template metaprogramming
  T a{typename helper<false>::type()};
  T b{typename helper<true>::type()};

  T c{get_arg<false>()};
  T d{get_arg<true>()};

  // Then do stuff with the suitably-constructed instance of T
  // . . .
}

int main(void) {
  try_construct<test>();

  return 0;
}
```

Compiler output:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -c foo.cpp 
foo.cpp: In instantiation of 'void try_construct() [with T = test]':
foo.cpp:38:23:   required from here
foo.cpp:30:37: error: no matching function for call to 'test::test(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
   T a{typename helper<false>::type()};
                                     ^
foo.cpp:30:37: note: candidates are:
foo.cpp:22:3: note: test::test(Tag)
   test(Tag x) { cout << "test(Tag)\n"; }
   ^
foo.cpp:22:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'void' to 'Tag'
foo.cpp:21:3: note: test::test()
   test(void) { cout << "test(void)\n"; }
   ^
foo.cpp:21:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
foo.cpp:33:23: error: no matching function for call to 'test::test(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
   T c{get_arg<false>()};
                       ^
foo.cpp:33:23: note: candidates are:
foo.cpp:22:3: note: test::test(Tag)
   test(Tag x) { cout << "test(Tag)\n"; }
   ^
foo.cpp:22:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'helper<false>::type {aka void}' to 'Tag'
foo.cpp:21:3: note: test::test()
   test(void) { cout << "test(void)\n"; }
   ^
foo.cpp:21:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

We know how to test on the presence of the constructor, so I've left that our of the example. If that does end up being relevant in a solution taking a different approach, feel free to go that route.

Our ultimate goal is to require one of the default constructor or the `Tag` constructor, and neither of the copy or move constructors.

Comment: And I now realize after asking and having gotten good answers to this question that in the context of use, we will actually need a move or copy constructor anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something along these lines works:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, bool B = std::is_constructible<Tag, T>> struct H;
template <typename T>
struct H<T, false> {
  T t;
  H() : t() {}
};
template <typename T>
struct H<T, true> {
  T t;
  H() : t(Tag) {}
};

try_construct() {
  H<T> h;
  h.t;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
namespace details {
  template<class T>
  T maybe_tag_construct(std::true_type) {
    return T(Tag{});
  }
  template<class T>
  T maybe_tag_construct(std::false_type) {
    return T();
  }
}
template<class T>
T maybe_tag_construct() {
  return details::maybe_tag_construct<T>( std::is_constructible<T, Tag>{} );
}
```

now `auto t =maybe_tag_construct<test>();` constructs `test` from `Tag` iff it works.

It also does elided move construction before [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), and in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) no move construction occurs.

In order to pass an instance of `void` around, you need the "regular void" proposal, which is on track for [c++2a](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b2a) last I checked.

Comment: This is pretty close to what we've tried, but in pre-C++17, as you note, it still requires that the move constructor (or fallback copy constructor, with the move constructor not `= delete;`) be defined on the type. I'll hold off on accepting this for now.